# Batch file automatically closes

Tags: batch-file

I have a problem. My batch file closes prematurely and I don't know why.

My code:

http://pastebin.com/zyG19nC2

too big for this thread.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not looking through all of that. At what point does it prematurely close (how far into the script does it get)?

Comment: It closes when it makes a new cmd window.

Comment: Who wrote the script and do you understand what it's supposed to accomplish for the most part... Looks a bit ugly with a ton of logic that's not needed for the root task...

Comment: Create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) or [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not putting code in an external link

Comment: `It closes when it makes a new cmd window.` is too vague. When does it make a new cmd window? In which line? There are tons of pointless `echo`s with useless `@` in the code, and tons of useless `goto`s which jump to the next line

Comment: Are you saying it fails at line 21?

Comment: Two very simple ways to troubleshoot a batch file. 1) Execute the batch file from the cmd prompt. 2) If echo off is enabled in your batch file change it to echo on. By doing this you can see the exact line the batch file stops at and you can read any error messages it displays.

Answer (score 0):

As a starter, there is no label `:checkmc` despite line 34 saying `goto :checkmc`. I think it should say `goto :closemc`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Report of a quick CHECKCMD with
`0> "checkcmd.cmd" D:\tests\batch.cmd local call goto marke parenth error level`

Report says:

```
 Ueberpruefe D:\transa\batch.cmd

 LOCAL
Keine Local/exit gefunden!

 CALL
Keinen CALL Sprunganfang gefunden!

 GOTO
13:    goto UACPrompt
14:) else ( goto gotAdmin )
28:    goto :admincheck
34:goto :checkmc
81:if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :begin
82:if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :closemc
83:goto :choice10
103:if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :forge
104:if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :forgemods
105:goto :choice
125:if /I "%c%" EQU "A" goto :forgeauto
126:if /I "%c%" EQU "M" goto :forgemanual
127:goto :choice2
152:goto :forgemods
177:goto :forgemods
197:if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :forgemodsyes
198:if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :regedit
199:goto :choicemods
227:goto :regedit
248:if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :regedityes
249:if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :connection
250:goto :choicereg
277:goto :connection
298:if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :connectionyes
299:if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :ramoptions
300:goto :choicecon
323:goto :ramoptions
343:if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :ramyes
344:if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :video
345:goto :choice4
369:goto :video
386:if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :openvideo
387:if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :finished
388:goto :choice4
413:goto :finished


 :MARKE
3::BatchGotAdmin
16::UACPrompt
25::gotAdmin
30::admincheck
60::closemc
79::choice10
85::begin
101::choice
107::forge
123::choice2
129::forgeauto
154::forgemanual
179::forgemods
195::choicemods
201::forgemodsyes
229::regedit
246::choicereg
252::regedityes
272::choice3
279::connection
296::choicecon
302::connectionyes
325::ramoptions
341::choice4
347::ramyes
371::video
384::choice4
390::openvideo
415::finished


 PARENTH
5:    IF "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" EQU "amd64" (
7:) ELSE (
9:)
12:if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
14:) else ( goto gotAdmin )
17:    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs
"
32:IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
35:) else (


 ERROR
Keine FOR -Errors gefunden!

 Level
64" (
5:    IF "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" EQU "amd64" (
  BEGIN ( BLOCK
5-- in:  47
 -- LEVEL = 1

) ELS
LSE (
7:) ELSE (
7-- in:  8 out:  1
 -- LEVEL = 1

)
9:)
9-- out:  1
  End BLOCK )
 -- LEVEL = 0

'0' (
12:if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
  BEGIN ( BLOCK
12-- in:  27
 -- LEVEL = 1

) els
lse (
)
14:) else ( goto gotAdmin )
14-- in:  8 out:  1 24
  End BLOCK )
 -- LEVEL = 0

ect^(
) > "
17:    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs
"
17-- in:  33 out:  54
 -- LEVEL = 0

U 0 (
32:IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
  BEGIN ( BLOCK
32-- in:  23
 -- LEVEL = 1

) els
lse (
35:) else (
35-- in:  8 out:  1
 -- LEVEL = 1
```

if Level gtr 0 you have not set current closing parenth